# Get Unity style notifications in Gnome Classic?

Tags: unity, notification, gnome-classic, notify-osd

I prefer the look of Unity's notifications as opposed to Gnome's. How can I get it? Or at least some thing that looks similar?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you are seeing together with the version of ubuntu you are using?  In 12.04 gnome-classic the notification looks like the unity notification bubble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in unity, the packages `libnotify4`, `notify-bin` and `notification-daemon` manage the notifications

for reference, you send a notification with `notify-send (message text)`. There's a load of options in the `man` page for stuff like titles and icons too. It's neat.